# Grouping by date column and applying a function to group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I tried asking a question earlier, but deleted so I could ask clearer and show what I am trying if it is close.

My sample df is

```
    day         a   b
  5/11/19       3   1
  5/11/19       4   6
  5/12/19       1   2
  5/12/19       5   9
  5/13/19      11   14
```

I want to group by the day column and want to have a new df that calculates for both col a and col b the number of values that are < 10 / all values for that day and column ( a or b) as a %. Since there are numerous rows for each day.

I am trying something like

```
def calc_(group_df):
result = dict()
result["x"] = group_df[(group_df.x) < 10] / len(group_df.x)
result["y"] = group_df[(group_df.y) < 10] / len(group_df.y)
return pd.Series(result, index=["x", "y"])
```

and then

```
df.groupby("day").apply(calc)
```

but I am getting error of

***TypeError: Could not operate 163143 with block values unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'***

Am I missing something?

I want my final output

```
     day         a   b
  5/11/19       .3  .1
  5/12/19       .5  .9
  5/13/19       .1  .4
```

I want it grouped by the business day and want each business day to show up only once in my final output.

Comment: your data types are mismatched you are dividing a `string` by and `integer`

Comment: @Chris thanks sir, is there anyway I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you want your final dataframe to look like but it looks like this is something you can do.

Using this dataframe as input:

```
       day   a   b
0  5/11/19   3   1
1  5/11/19  11   3
2  5/12/19   5   9
3  5/13/19  11  14

def calc(df):

    len_a_under_10 = (df['a'] < 10).sum() / len(df['a'])
    len_b_under_10 = (df['b'] < 10).sum() / len(df['b'])

    df['a_under_10'] = len_a_under_10
    df['b_under_10'] = len_b_under_10

return df

df.groupby('day').apply(calc)
```

Gives:

```
       day   a   b  a_under_10  b_under_10
0  5/11/19   3   1         0.5         1.0
1  5/11/19  11   3         0.5         1.0
2  5/12/19   5   9         1.0         1.0
3  5/13/19  11  14         0.0         0.0
```

Comment: this seems close, but the only thing it doesn't do is group by the day my final output when I try this has multiple rows for each day when I want only one row for each day, does that make sense? sorry for the confusion